# Display number of products within filter in Magento sidebar

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I'm currently building out a site using Magento 1.7 where the total number of products displayed in a category is displayed in the sidebar (*template/category/layer/view.phtml* in the theme directory). The code I have to display this value at the moment is as follows:

`<div class="products-total">
      <?php if (Mage::registry('current_category')) { ?>
        <?php $_category_detail->getName();?>
        <?php $_category_detail->getId(); ?>
        <?php $products_count = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category_detail->getId())
                ->getProductCount();
        ?>
        <?php echo $products_count,' products' ?>
      <?php } ?>
    </div>`

However, as it simply pulls the current category total products value, it doesn't account for filters. How would it be possible to show the filtered products total?

Comment: I think you make mistake in this line <?php echo $products_count,' products' ?>